# Script working on Chrome but not on Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have this fixed element to the right of the page. Here is its CSS code:

```
#rightSide {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 613px;
  width: 450px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
  background-color: #fafafa;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0px;
  display: block;
  float: right;
  padding: 0;
  z-index: 200;
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
  <div id="rightSide"></div>
</body>
```

What I want to do with this page is: when there is a window resize, the element is only fixed vertically, and it would scroll with the page horizontally. Here is the Javascript I use (resize and scroll are jQuery events):

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  var bod = $('body').innerWidth();
  var wid = $(this).innerWidth();
  var wind = bod - wid;
  $('#rightSide').css("right", '-'+ wind +'px');
  $(this).scroll(function () {
    var scrleft = $('body').scrollLeft();
    var scrl = scrleft - wind;
    $('#rightSide').css("right", scrl +'px');
  });
});
```

What's weird is that this code works just fine on Chrome, but not on Firefox. Do you have any idea why this is happening?

Thanks!

**EDIT** Here is the body CSS if it helps.

```
body {
  width : 100%;
  min-width: 1070px;
  height : 100%;
  margin : 0px auto 0px auto;
  padding : 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  display: block;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: auto;
  min-height: 613px;
}
```

Comment: I created a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bhM4m/1/) and I do not see any difference between Chrome and Firefox. Could you describe the problem in a bit more detail?

Comment: Well, on firefox, this line works:
$('#rightSide').css("right", '-'+ wind +'px'); 
But not the rest, not the scroll part. On chrome, everything works just fine.

Comment: You have a logic flaw, possibly related to this problem. `$(this).scroll(function () {` this scroll event will be bound once for every time the window resize event happens, possibly getting bound hundreds of times eventually causing the page to crash.

Comment: You really don't need JavaScript for this.  Look at CSS `position: fixed`.  http://jsfiddle.net/AmQDs/

Comment: @Sparky672 if I use only css for this as you suggested, when the window is small enough, the fixed div is going to hide all the content that is on the left side of the page. What I need is that after a resize, the fixed element behaves like it's absolute horizontally but stays fixed vertically, and I don't think that's feasible with only css. something like the second div here: demo.rickyh.co.uk/css-position-x-and-position-y

Comment: @KevinB that's a good point. Maybe chrome is more 'fault tolerant' vis-à-vis this kind of programming mistakes. I will try to find a way to execute it only once, if you have any suggestions that would be awesome. Thanks!

Comment: Just unbind it, `.off("scroll").scroll(...` or pre-1.7.2: `.unbind("scroll").scroll(...` however you may want to namespace it if it's possible for other plugins or code to be binding to the scroll event.

Comment: @KevinB Ok, thanks for the tip, I still have the same problem though..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found the origin of the problem, it appears that under Firefox and IE, to correctly use scrollLeft, it has to be done with `document` not `body`, something like:

```
var scrleft = $(document).scrollLeft();
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need script for something like this. The `position: fixed; right:0;` CSS should be enough. Also, take out the `float: right;` style; it is unnecessary, and doesn't make sense with absolute/fixed positioning. You don't need `display:block` either - divs are block by default.

Comment: I removed the float and display, but if I use only css for this as you suggested, when the window is small enough, the fixed div is going to hide all the content that is on the left side of the page. What I need is that after a resize, the fixed element behaves like it's absolute horizontally but stays fixed vertically, and I don't think that's feasible with only css.
something like the second div here: http://demo.rickyh.co.uk/css-position-x-and-position-y/